# We cannot start a new Activity by using an intent when context has been destroy? Am I right?

Tags: android, android-context

We cannot start a new Activity by using an intent when context has been destroy? Am I right?
And Why I can start an activity when I press back button while Thread is running?

Here is my code below

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: app close after you press back ?

Comment: what are you want? and what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry I just want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't start the activity since the action onBackPressed() while your thread is sleeping will trigger an InterruptedException.

To start the activity anyway, you can move the intent inside the catch block like this.

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}

}
```